Vertical space without grey quotation box
hello my name is Mike..
good to meet You all

..i am new here, question is

how do i do Big spaces without grey box?
i tried doing enters, to make spaces,
Only the grey box with spaces in front lets enters show.. 
it says do not make code?.. thanks, Mike

Also, don't use tags that have nothing to do with your question.

thanks Nate Eldredge, Tags box said hashing block ripple, Sorry

The idea is that you should participate in the main site first before using meta.  You get reputation by posting useful questions and answers that people vote up.  Also, the tags in the tags box were as examples only.  I'd suggest that you spend some time looking at the existing questions on the site to get a sense of how it works, then it will be easier to see what makes good questions and answers.  In the meantime, perhaps a moderator can migrate your question to meta.

okay thanks.. How do big spaces in Comments ..? mike

I don't know.  Comments are not a good place to ask new questions, either.

You can control the size of spaces by adding non-breakable spaces into your text with the html symbol &nbsp;.
This would create a                      space like the one in this line.
You can add a line break
by putting "two spaces" at the end of the line
which will allow you continue writing in the next line.
You can also add new paragraphs by  inserting the html code <p> ... </p>.

but.. how do i put in Tall space ?

Oh, right, vertical space. Do you mean, how to force a line-break?

yes.. grey box with spaces before makes enters appear... Enters on same line without grey box..? thanks, mike

Hi Mike, I updated to include linebreaks.
